# Select tds that are in row with th with specified content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to add a class to td's which are part of a row with a th with specified contents. This is the table I am working with:

**HTML**

```
<table id="lastPeriodComparison">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="right">Users</th>
      <th class="right">Page Views</th>
      <th class="right">Sessions</th>
      <th class="right">Page Views per Session</th>
      <th class="right">Average Session Duration</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Previous Period</th>
      <td class="right">6672</td>
      <td class="right">47810</td>
      <td class="right">9208</td>
      <td class="right">5.192</td>
      <td class="right">0:03:25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">This Period</th>
      <td class="right">7401</td>
      <td class="right">48796</td>
      <td class="right">10414</td>
      <td class="right">4.686</td>
      <td class="right">0:03:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Change</th>
      <td class="right">729</td>
      <td class="right">986</td>
      <td class="right">1206</td>
      <td class="right">-0.507</td>
      <td class="right">-0:00:07</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Percent Change</th>
      <td class="right">10.93%</td>
      <td class="right">2.06%</td>
      <td class="right">13.10%</td><td class="right">-9.76%</td>
      <td class="right">-3.40%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the following in jQuery, which is correctly selecting the `th` with scope of row which has the word `Change` in it, and applying a class:

**jQuery**

```
$('th[scope="row"]:contains("Change")').addClass('negcheck');
```

What I need to do is apply that class to the `td`s in the row, to end up with the following HTML for the last two rows:

**HTML**

```
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Change</th>
      <td class="right negcheck">729</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">986</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">1206</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">-0.507</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">-0:00:07</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Percent Change</th>
      <td class="right negcheck">10.93%</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">2.06%</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">13.10%</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">-9.76%</td>
      <td class="right negcheck">-3.40%
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Eventually I am going to use jQuery to check the contents of the `td.negcheck` and style them differently depending on if the contents is positive or negative.

Help greatly appreciated - I am sure it is simple but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 $("tr th:contains('Change')").each(function(){
                    $(this).parent('tr').children('td').addClass('negcheck');
    });
```

OR

```
$('th[scope="row"]:contains("Change")').parent('tr').children('td').addClass('negcheck');
```

Please check this example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('th[scope="row"]:contains("Change")').parent('tr').children('td').addClass('negcheck');  
});
```

```css
.negcheck {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="lastPeriodComparison">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="right">Users</th>
      <th class="right">Page Views</th>
      <th class="right">Sessions</th>
      <th class="right">Page Views per Session</th>
      <th class="right">Average Session Duration</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Previous Period</th>
      <td class="right">6672</td>
      <td class="right">47810</td>
      <td class="right">9208</td>
      <td class="right">5.192</td>
      <td class="right">0:03:25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">This Period</th>
      <td class="right">7401</td>
      <td class="right">48796</td>
      <td class="right">10414</td>
      <td class="right">4.686</td>
      <td class="right">0:03:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Change</th>
      <td class="right">729</td>
      <td class="right">986</td>
      <td class="right">1206</td>
      <td class="right">-0.507</td>
      <td class="right">-0:00:07</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Percent Change</th>
      <td class="right">10.93%</td>
      <td class="right">2.06%</td>
      <td class="right">13.10%</td>
      <td class="right">-9.76%</td>
      <td class="right">-3.40%</td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
$('th:contains(Change)").parent().find('.right').filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.trim().indexOf('-') === 0;
}).addClass('negcheck');
```